# How can I get all values by same class through Xpath?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, python-requests

Try to learn about Xpath scraping but can not make it.

When I use Xpath helper plugin in Chrome, I can get the data like that. about 99 ports, the last one is "$PORT"

[Xpath info screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bd4VD.png)

```
import requests
import csv
from lxml import etree

url = 'https://www.msccruisesusa.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/MSC_SearchCruiseManagerRedirectCmd?storeId=12264&langId=-1004&catalogId=10001&monthsResult=&areaFilter=MED%40NOR%40&embarkFilter=&lengthFilter=&departureFrom=01.11.2020&departureTo=04.11.2020&ships=&category=&onlyAvailableCruises=true&packageTrf=false&packageTpt=false&packageCrol=false&packageCrfl=false&noAdults=2&noChildren=0&noJChildren=0&noInfant=0&dealsInput=false&tripSpecificationPanel=true&shipPreferencesPanel=false&dealsPanel=false'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36'}
source = requests.get(url,headers=headers).content.decode('UTF-8')

html = etree.HTML(source)

portList = html.xpath('//*[@class="cr-city-name"]')

for port in portList:
    print(port.xpath('string()'))
```

With this CODE, only return the "$PORT" to me, and I want to know why I can not get the other 98 ports data from this Xpath?

Answer (score 0):

Data of your page filled dynamically using `Javascript` from `JSON`. But `JSON` does not load through the `XHR`. You can find `JSON` is in `HTML` and you can extract `JSON` using `Regex` and convert `JSON` to `Dictionary`.

```
import re
import requests

url = 'https://www.msccruisesusa.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/MSC_SearchCruiseManagerRedirectCmd?storeId=12264&langId=-1004&catalogId=10001&monthsResult=&areaFilter=MED%40NOR%40&embarkFilter=&lengthFilter=&departureFrom=01.11.2020&departureTo=04.11.2020&ships=&category=&onlyAvailableCruises=true&packageTrf=false&packageTpt=false&packageCrol=false&packageCrfl=false&noAdults=2&noChildren=0&noJChildren=0&noInfant=0&dealsInput=false&tripSpecificationPanel=true&shipPreferencesPanel=false&dealsPanel=false'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)

# Extract JSON from HTML.
json_data = re.findall(r"_ports = {\n\s\s(.+?)\n\s\s};", response.text)

# Convert String to Dictionary.
json_data = eval('{' + json_data[0] + '}')

print(json_data.values())
```

Output:

```
dict_values(['Aqaba, Jordan', 'Valencia, Spain', 'Cairs, Australia', 'Venice, Italy', 'Shekou, China', 'Shanghai, China', 'Goteborg, Sweden', 'Darwin, Australia', 'George Town, Cayman Islands', 'Siracusa, Italy', 'Genoa, Italy', 'Reykjavik, Iceland', 'Havana, Cuba', 'Singapore, Republic of Singapore', 'Arica, Chile', 'Hamburg,Germany', 'Kusadasi, Turkey', 'Yokohama, Japan', 'Valparaiso,Chile', 'Copenhagen, Denmark', 'Civitavecchia, Italy', 'Barcelona, Spain', 'Auckland, New Zealand', 'Livorno, Italy', 'Montevideo, Uruguay', 'Brindisi, Italy', 'Kiel,Germany', 'San Juan, Puerto Rico', 'Callao, Peru', 'Funchal, Portugal', 'Haifa, Israel', 'Lisbon, Portugal', 'Papeete, Tahiti', 'Trieste, Italy', 'Piraeus, Greece', 'Rio de Janeiro, Brazil', 'Keelung, Taiwan', 'Buenos Aires, Argentina', 'New York, United States', 'Salvador, Brazil', 'Tianjin, China', 'Valletta, Malta', 'Santos, Brazil', 'Cannes, France', 'Naples, Italy', 'Fukuoka, Japan', 'Ushuaia,Argentina', 'Philipsburg, St. Maarten', 'Zeebrugge, Belgium', 'Durban, South Africa', 'Istanbul, Turkey', 'Cagliari, Italy', 'Vigo, Spain', 'Dubai,U.Arab Emirates', 'Amsterdam, Netherlands', 'Tampa, United States', 'Doha, Qatar', 'Abu Dhabi,U.Arab Emirates', 'Itajai, Brazil', 'Port Kembla, Australia', 'Tokyo, Japan', 'Cartagena, Spain', 'Nassau, Bahamas', 'Messina, Italy', 'Benoa/Bali, Indonesia', 'Nansha,China', 'Heraklion, Greece', 'Mumbai/Bombay, India', 'Muscat, Oman', 'Wellington, New Zealand', 'Warnemunde,Germany', 'Fort de France, Martinique', 'Isafjordur, Iceland', 'Bridgetown, Barbados', 'Marseille, France', 'Sydney, Australia', 'Miami, Florida', 'Cozumel, Mexico', 'Rotterdam, Netherlands', 'Izmir, Turkey', 'Cape Town, South Africa', 'Qingdao, China', 'Palma de Mallorca, Spain', 'San Francisco, United states', 'Hobart, Australia', 'Malaga, Spain', 'Palermo, Italy', 'St Nazaire, France', 'Mindelo, Cape Verde', 'Pointe-a-Pitre, Guadeloupe', 'Hong Kong,Hong Kong', 'Le Havre, France', 'Ocean Cay MSC Marine Reserve', 'St Petersburg, Russian Fed.', 'Ilhabela, Brazil', 'Ancona, Italy', ......., 'Corner Brook, Canada', 'Brunsbuttel,Germany', 'Newcastle, Australia', 'Busan, Korea, Republic of', 'Maputo, Mozambique'])
```

Or you can use `Selenium` `ChromeDriver` which load `Javascript` into `HTML`. So you can extract those data using `lxml`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from lxml import etree

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"***YOUR_CHROME-DRIVER_PATH***")
driver.get('https://www.msccruisesusa.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/MSC_SearchCruiseManagerRedirectCmd?storeId=12264&langId=-1004&catalogId=10001&monthsResult=&areaFilter=MED%40NOR%40&embarkFilter=&lengthFilter=&departureFrom=01.11.2020&departureTo=04.11.2020&ships=&category=&onlyAvailableCruises=true&packageTrf=false&packageTpt=false&packageCrol=false&packageCrfl=false&noAdults=2&noChildren=0&noJChildren=0&noInfant=0&dealsInput=false&tripSpecificationPanel=true&shipPreferencesPanel=false&dealsPanel=false')

html = etree.HTML(driver.page_source)
driver.close()

portList = html.xpath('//*[@class="cr-city-name"]')

for port in portList:
    print(port.xpath('string()'), end=' | ')
```

Output:

```
Marseille, France | Genoa, Italy | Civitavecchia, Italy | Palermo, Italy | Valletta, Malta | Barcelona, Spain | Marseille, France | MSC Grandiosa | Marseille, France | Genoa, Italy | Civitavecchia, Italy | Palermo, Italy | Valletta, Malta | Barcelona, Spain | Marseille, France | MSC Grandiosa | Genoa, Italy | Civitavecchia, Italy | Palermo, Italy | Valletta, Malta | Barcelona, Spain | Marseille, France | Genoa, Italy | MSC Grandiosa | Genoa, Italy | Civitavecchia, Italy | Palermo, Italy | Valletta, Malta | Barcelona, Spain | Marseille, France | Genoa, Italy | MSC Grandiosa | Civitavecchia, Italy | Palermo, Italy | Valletta, Malta | Barcelona, Spain | Marseille, France | Genoa, Italy | MSC Grandiosa | Civitavecchia, Italy | Palermo, Italy | Valletta, Malta | Barcelona, Spain | Marseille, France | Genoa, Italy | MSC Grandiosa | Palermo, Italy | Valletta, Malta | Barcelona, Spain | Marseille, France | Genoa, Italy | Civitavecchia, Italy | Palermo, Italy | MSC Grandiosa | Palermo, Italy | Valletta, Malta | Barcelona, Spain | Marseille, France | Genoa, Italy | Civitavecchia, Italy | Palermo, Italy | MSC Grandiosa | Barcelona, Spain | Marseille, France | Genoa, Italy | Civitavecchia, Italy | Palermo, Italy | Valletta, Malta | Barcelona, Spain | MSC Grandiosa | Barcelona, Spain | Marseille, France | Genoa, Italy | Civitavecchia, Italy | Palermo, Italy | Valletta, Malta | Barcelona, Spain | MSC Grandiosa | Civitavecchia, Italy | Genoa, Italy | Malaga, Spain | Funchal, Portugal | Santa Cruz de Tenerife, Spain | Tangier, Morocco | Cartagena, Spain | Civitavecchia, Italy | MSC Opera | Civitavecchia, Italy | Genoa, Italy | Malaga, Spain | Funchal, Portugal | Santa Cruz de Tenerife, Spain | Tangier, Morocco | Cartagena, Spain | Civitavecchia, Italy | MSC Opera | $PORT |
```

You can download ChromeDriver from [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but those ports data was not my want, the port data Xpath positioned was the port photo slider's  text name, such as #slideShow-1 > div > div > div.cr-image-container-slider.slick-slide.slick-current.slick-active > span. There a 99 photos in product intro slider, and I have to get those ports data.

Comment: Then you have to use `Selenium` webdriver.